# Incorrect activity result code after rotating activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities A and B.  A launches activity B.  In activity B I call setResult(RESULT_OK, intent) in a button click handler without calling finish() - which is the desirable behavior.

After rotating B and pressing back, A's onActivityResult receives RESULT_CANCELED for resultCode, rather than RESULT_OK.

I know this is caused by the fact that activity B was destroyed upon rotation.  What's the common practice to make sure the correct result code is returned from B?

My initial thought is to save up mResultCode in onSaveInstanceState.

Comment: You need to set the result again in onRestoreInstanceState method

Comment: Should I do it in onRestoreIsntanceState or onCreate?

Comment: Yes, you need to set it in onRestoreInstanceState

Comment: Thanks - putting it in onCreate and checking bundle for non-null seems to work as well though.

Comment: Yes, that would also work.
onRestoreInstanceState is called after onStart() when the activity is being re-initialized from a previously saved state,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save result in onSaveInstanceState and set the result again in onRestoreInstanceState method.

> onRestoreInstanceState :
>
> This method is called after onStart() when the activity is being
>   re-initialized from a previously saved state, given here in
>   savedInstanceState. Most implementations will simply use
>   onCreate(Bundle) to restore their state, but it is sometimes
>   convenient to do it here after all of the initialization has been done
>   or to allow subclasses to decide whether to use your default
>   implementation. The default implementation of this method performs a
>   restore of any view state that had previously been frozen by
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle).
>
> This method is called between onStart() and onPostCreate(Bundle).